# How do you measure the footprints of a Javascript application?

Tags: extjs, javascript-framework, footprint

What actually is referred to when mentioning the footprints of an application? And how can one measure the footprints in case of a Javascript application built using a framework/library like ExtJs?

Thanks for any guidance in advance.